# React - prevent Form's onChange event from setting parent state until Enter key is hit

Tags: reactjs, forms

A child class `Search` has a form input that expects some string to searched for (example: some area in the city). The parent component `App` stores that searched value in state in order to pass it as a prop to another method (the `Map` component).

Problem: when I begin typing into the search form, the `searchedValue` is updated immediately in the parent (obv because of the `onSearchedInputChange` method`) -

**how would I make the form wait until I click `Enter` before updating parent state?**

**App.js (Parent)**

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    searchedValue: "",
    searchedResponse: null
  };

handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    ...
  };

  onSearchedInputChange = searchedValue => {
    this.setState({
      searchedValue: searchedValue
    });
  };
```

**Search.js (child)**

```
class Search extends Component {
  handleSubmit = e => {
    this.props.handleSubmit(e);
  };
  // pass callback to parent with searched field
  handleSearch = e => {
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
      this.props.onSearchedInputChange(e.target.value);
    }
  };

  render() {
    const searchedValue = this.props.searchedValue;
    return (
      <div className="search">
        <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <Form.Group controlId="searchForm" className="search-form">
            <InputGroup>
              <InputGroup.Prepend>
                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSearch} className="search-icon" />
              </InputGroup.Prepend>
              <Form.Control
                className="search-input"
                type="text"
                placeholder="Enter street or area..."
                value={searchedValue}
                name="search"
                onChange={this.handleSearch}
              />
            </InputGroup>
          </Form.Group>
        </Form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should save input value in child state then pass it, after that handle key event to check if enter is clicked then pass the child state `searchTerm` to parent class by two way binding. So after you finish typing the text will be saved in `searchTerm` state, when you click on Enter then call the function from the prop and pass `searchTerm` to the parent class.

This is the code:

```
class Search extends Component {
  state = {
    searchTerm: ""
  };

  handleSubmit = e => {
    this.props.handleSubmit(e);
  };

  handleSearch = e => {
    this.setState({ searchTerm: e.target.value });
  };

  handleKeyPress = e => {
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
      this.props.onSearchedInputChange(this.state.searchTerm);
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="search">
        <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <Form.Group controlId="searchForm" className="search-form">
            <InputGroup>
              <InputGroup.Prepend>
                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSearch} className="search-icon" />
              </InputGroup.Prepend>
              <Form.Control
                className="search-input"
                type="text"
                placeholder="Enter street or area..."
                value={this.state.searchTerm}
                name="search"
                onChange={this.handleSearch}
                onKeyPress={this.handleKeyPress.bind(this)}
              />
            </InputGroup>
          </Form.Group>
        </Form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: after trying this, typing into the form renders no text. when I console log `e.target.value` I can see the characters that I am typing but I cannot see it in the input form itself. do u know why?

Comment: ah I got it. I was passing `searchedValue` in props. that was the mistake. I was supposed to set value to `this.state.searchTerm`. You can update the answer and I will accept it. cheers

Comment: u didn't updated the code. 1. remove `const searchedValue` assignment. 2. change `value={searchedValue}` to `value={this.state.searchTerm}`

Comment: Aha I see, the value of textInput should be `searchTerm`